# How to split the text file into rows and columns and save in excel using python

Tags: python

[Screenshot of text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYGn.png)

I have a text file with a long sequence of data(combination of integer and string values) and I want to split the text file into rows and columns and then finally save the data  into excel file using python.I tried to convert this file into csv but everything is getting stored into a single row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiPlV.png)

I want the data to be splitted into different rows and columns based on the spacing. I tried with split function but its not working.

Comment: Please don't give a screenshot. Can you put the text inside of the post itself?

Comment: Read the file with [df = pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) then write the DataFrame using `df.to_excel()`. The pandas docs are very good.

Comment: Additionally, is there a requirement for the file to be in Excel?  If not, I’d strongly recommend storing as CSV due to portability and ease of reading and parsing by other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `pandas`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_table('filename.txt')
>>> df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

In the `read_table()` method, adjust the delimiter method by using the `sep=` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had already tried with this approach. Files are getting converted but it is not getting splitted into different rows and columns.

Comment: It sounds like you need to make sure you use the proper delimiter